# What does no_ready_check means in redis client argument

Tags: node.js, redis

```
var dbConnection = redis.createClient(config.db.port, config.db.host, {no_ready_check: true});
```

What does it means and works?

```
{no_ready_check: true}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [explained](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#overloading) in the [documentation](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#connect):

- `no_ready_check`: defaults to `false`. When a connection is established to the Redis server, the server might still
  be loading the database from disk.  While loading, the server not respond to any commands.  To work around this,
  `node_redis` has a "ready check" which sends the `INFO` command to the server.  The response from the `INFO` command
  indicates whether the server is ready for more commands.  When ready, `node_redis` emits a `ready` event.
  Setting `no_ready_check` to `true` will inhibit this check.